# Error when running GeoServer with GWC S3 BlobStore plugin installed

Tags: geoserver, geowebcache, amazon-web-services

I have GeoServer 2.13 installed and I would like to use the GWC S3 BlobStore plugin which I downloaded from here:

http://ares.opengeo.org/geoserver/master/community-latest/geoserver-2.13-SNAPSHOT-gwc-s3-plugin.zip

I followed the instructions from here:

http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/community/gwc-s3/index.html

I unzipped the contents into WEB-INF/lib directory as per the instructions however when I startup GeoServer I get a bunch of errors, here is the log file:

https://pastebin.com/BYdR4jp9

I believe this question has been asked a few years ago, but I couldn't find it. I remember the answer being that the nightly build was problematic. Does anyone know if this is the case again or how to fix the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ares.opengeo.org has not been the official build server for a long while now, the last builds on ares are 6 months old.

Check https://build.geoserver.org/geoserver/ instead.
Also remember that's a community plugin, e.g, unsupported, and that it should be used with the corresponding nightly build of GeoServer, instead of an official release (using it with an official release you might stumble into API differences).

Comment: The newer version from https://build.geoserver.org/geoserver/ worked. Thank you!